# Execute a shell command with python variables

Tags: python, subprocess

I had script on bash where I generated username, password, ssh-key for user.
Part for creating of ssh-key:

```
su $user -c "ssh-keygen -f /home/$user/.ssh/id_rsa -t rsa -b 4096 -N ''"
```

How can I do the same in Python with `os.system`? I tried this:

```
os.system('su %s -c "ssh-keygen -f /home/%s/.ssh/id_rsa -t rsa -b 4096 -N ''"', user)
TypeError: system() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

Also I tried:

```
os.system('su user -c "ssh-keygen -f /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa -t rsa -b 4096 -N ''"')
```

Of course, it doesn't work either.

Comment: note that the same command with `$user` would work with `os.system` since it creates a shell.

Comment: `os.system('su $user -c "ssh-keygen -f /home/$user/.ssh/id_rsa -t rsa -b 4096 -N ''"')`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre sorry, it does not see key -N `option requires an argument -- N
usage: ssh-keygen [-q] [-b bits] [-t dsa | ecdsa | ed25519 | rsa | rsa1]`

Comment: ok we're getting close: `os.system('su $user -c "ssh-keygen -f /home/$user/.ssh/id_rsa -t rsa -b 4096 -N \'\'"'`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre good. How i forgot about this. And my example with python is working. Thanks

Comment: I've created a real answer, since it's not so bad a question after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.system` is very close to a `bash` command line because it uses an underlying shell (like its cousins `subprocess.call`... using `shell=True`)

In your case, there's little interest using `subprocess` since your command runs a command, so you cannot really use argument protection by `subprocess` fully.

Pass the exact command, but the only change would be to protect the simple quotes, else python sees that as string end+string start (your string is protected by simple quotes already) and they're eliminated.

Check this simpler example:

```
>>> 'hello '' world'
'hello  world'
>>> 'hello \'\' world'
"hello '' world"
```

that's a kind of worst-case when you cannot use either double or simple quotes to protect the string because you're using the other flavour within. In that case, escape the quotes using `\`:

```
os.system('su $user -c "ssh-keygen -f /home/$user/.ssh/id_rsa -t rsa -b 4096 -N \'\'"')
```

Answer (score 2):

Format your instructions with the `os` package; for instance:

```
import os

user = 'joe'
ssh_dir = "/home/{}/.ssh/id_rsa".format(user)
os.system("ssh-keygen -f {} -t rsa -b 4096 -N ''".format(ssh_dir))
```

Comment: You spoke right, @JohnKugelman: I edited with the command from the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use the subprocess module:

```
import subprocess
username = 'user'
result, err = subprocess.Popen(
            'su %s -c "ssh-keygen -f /home/%s/.ssh/id_rsa -t rsa -b 4096 -N ''"' % (username, username),
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            shell=True
          ).communicate()
if err:
    print('Something went wrong')
else:
    print(result)
```

Edit: this is the 'fast' way to do that, you should't use `shell=True` if you can't control the input since it allows code execution as said [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments)

Comment: sorry, it does not see key -N `option requires an argument -- N usage: ssh-keygen [-q] [-b bits] [-t dsa | ecdsa | ed25519 | rsa | rsa1]`

Comment: look please ^ `option requires an argument -- N`

Comment: Sorry I didn't try the snippet, I' ll fix that when i' m back home